How to convert a row from a table to ENUM in JOOQ?
JOOQ does not convert rows from a table to enum
I tried different conversion methods, but they either didn't do anything, or they displayed errors, I tried to add codegen jooq, but I can't do it, I can't find documentation that clearly states what needs to be done.
return new PageImpl<>(DSL.select(field("kk.id"),
                        field("kk.epk_id"),
                        field("kk.uir"),
                        field("kk.status_code", VARCHAR.asEnumDataType(StatusCode.class)), --- This is the line that is not being converted
                        field("kk.end_date", DATE),
                        field("kk.sudir_user_name"),
                        field("val.name_kk")).
                from("ccl_test.calculation_kk kk\n" +
                        "join ccl_test.values_kk val\n" +
                        "on (case resulting_calculation_value\n" +
                        "    when 'value_ml_model' then id_ml_model_value=val.id\n" +
                        "    when 'value_lm' then id_lm_value=val.id\n" +
                        "    when 'value_verifier' then id_verifier_value=val.id\n" +
                        "    END)\n" +
                        "where status_code='completed'")
                .orderBy(field("kk.id"))
                .limit(pageable.getPageSize())
                .offset(pageable.getOffset())
                .fetchInto(CalculationDTOForAll.class));

This is my ENUM
public enum StatusCode {
    INITIATED("initiated","Инициирован"),
    ON_VERIFICATION("for_verification","На верификации"),
    ON_CONFIRMATION("confirmation","На подтверждении"),
    COMPLETED("completed","Завершен");
    private final String value;
    private final String codeName;

    StatusCode(String value, String codeName) {
        this.value = value;
        this.codeName = codeName;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getCodeName() {
        return codeName;
    }
}

this is my class --(this is not the main entity, but an auxiliary class)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CalculationDTOForAll {
    private Long        id;
    private Long        epkId;
    private String      uir;
    private StatusCode      statusCode; --- the same Enum that is not being converted
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date        endDate;
    private String      sudirUserName;
    private String      nameKk;
}


DataType.asEnumDataType() requires the argument enum type to implement jOOQ's org.jooq.EnumType interface, which your enum doesn't do.
You have three options to fix this:

Just implement this interface
Use a Converter via DataType.asConvertedDataType()
Attach a Converter to generated code, which I highly recommend you consider using, instead of using only jOOQ's string based APIs.


I can't set up codegen in jooq, maybe there are detailed instructions
